# How to create a picture composed of 4 sub-sub-figures with 4 sub-sub-captions and 2 sub-captions?

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

I want to create a page in overleaf contains 4 sub-sub-figures, each figure has a sub-sub-caption ?
each two sub-sub-figures have its own sub-caption, as illustrated in the bellow picture:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve this. This is a example using `subfig` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[title pic 1]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}\hspace{0.5cm}
\subfloat[title pic 2]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}\\
\caption*{A-picture (a) and (b)}
\subfloat[title pic 3]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}\hspace{0.5cm}\subfloat[title pic 4]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image}}\\
\caption*{B-picture (a) and (b)}
\caption{Figure title of all sub-pictures} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]